# SQL - Max Value for multiple time periods

Tags: sql

I'm looking to get the max value of a column for multiple time periods, where I know the StartDate and EndDate of each period

This is how my data looks

```
+--------+---------+-------------------+------------------+
| Values | Period  | Start Date Period | End Date Period  |
+--------+---------+-------------------+------------------+
| 1      | Period1 | 6/17/2020          |7/17/2020        |
| 2      | Period1 | 6/17/2020          |7/17/2020        |
| 3      | Period1 | 6/17/2020          |7/17/2020        |
| 1      | Period2 | 7/18/2020          |8/20/2020        |
| 5      | Period2 | 7/18/2020          |8/20/2020        |
| 4      | Period3 | 8/22/2020          |9/20/2020        |
+--------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

What I need to get from this would look like this..

```
+--------+---------+-------------------+------------------+
| Values | Period  | Start Date Period | End Date Period  |
+--------+---------+-------------------+------------------+
| 3      | Period1 | 6/17/2020          |7/17/2020        |
| 5      | Period2 | 7/18/2020          |8/20/2020        |
| 4      | Period3 | 8/22/2020          |9/20/2020        |
+--------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like aggregation:

```
select max(value), period, start_date, end_date
from t
group by period, start_date, end_date
```